# Always being initialised to 0, even though it's supposed to be random

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My code is supposed to get a random index, but whenever I run the code it returns an index of 0 every time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var randomIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf((flashcardUiState.indices).random()) }
```

Comment: Hello Allen check if flashcardUiState.indices is empty

Comment: Yes it was empty, that's why it was always returning 0. Thanks!